# Cordova / PhoneGap 3.1 iOS Blank Page with Remote Url

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm having a strange issue with PhoneGap 3.1 and embedding a webview. Here's what the app looks like after it launches: http://d.pr/i/5McX - It's the same issue on iOS 6.1 and iOS 7.0.3

I have the latest version of PhoneGap installed and I've been through the steps here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_ios_webview.md.html#iOS%20WebViews_adding_cleaver_to_the_xcode_project_cordovalib_sub_project

I didn't run into any issues with the config values and I believe everything is setup properly. The issue surfaces when I change `<content src="index.html" />` to `<content src="http://apache.org" />`

In `MainViewController.m`, I have this in the `viewDidLoad` function

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CDVViewController* viewController = [CDVViewController new];
    viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.view addSubview:viewController.view];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

All I'm trying to do is get a remote site to show up in the app instead of local files. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter

```
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*" />
```

to

```
<access origin="*" />
```

in your config.xml and try again.

lg fastrde

Answer (score 0):

You try to load a remote site onto the device.

This is forbidden for security reasons. If you want to show it:

- you will need a InAppBrowser.
- You may bypass your problem linke mentioned here:
  https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/dynamic_page_loading_for_phonegap1?lang=en
- Maybe you just need to setup the [domainwhitelist](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide).